# sObject type 'FlowTestCoverage' is not supported

Tags: code-coverage, visual-workflow

I am trying to run a query in the Developer Console to find the test coverage for a particular Flow I have created. However, I am getting the error:

> sObject type 'FlowTestCoverage' is not supported

Does anyone know how I can find my test class coverage or is I am doing something wrong?

**Query:**

```
SELECT Id, ApexTestClassId, TestMethodName, FlowVersionId, NumElementsCovered, NumElementsNotCovered
FROM FlowTestCoverage
WHERE flowversionid='3001C000000Tta4'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`FlowTestCoverage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowtestcoverage.htm) is part of Tooling API. If running from Query Editor in Developer Console, you need to enable `Use Tooling API` option in the Query Editor in Developer Console (option available besides Execute button, screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I did check that, but I don't get any rows in my results, nor do I get any errors below my query.

Comment: You will need to verify if the records do exist or not. But the root cause of the error that you received was because of the option not being checked.

Comment: Do you know if only Autolaunched Flows require test coverage, or all Flows?

Comment: Seems to include all, you can find more details on the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_test_coverage.htm).